# $Z_{n,N}$ convergence to $N(0,1)$ in law for all N, how to find $N_n$ s.t. $Z_{n,N_n}$ also converges to $N(0,1)$ in law?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

I'm reading Terence Tao's blog on [the central limit theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/).

When reducing the theorem to bounded random variables, let $$Z_{n, \leq N}:=\frac{S_{n, \leq N}-n \mu_{\leq N}}{\sqrt{n} \sigma_{\leq N}}$$ where $S_{n, \leq N}= (X_1+\cdots+X_n)_{\leq N}$, and ${\mu_{\leq N}, \sigma_{\leq N}^2}$ be the mean and variance of the bounded random variable ${(X_i){_{\leq N}}}$. Assuming the CLT in the bounded case, we know that $\forall N$, $Z_{n, \leq N}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. Now he uses the a **diagonalization argument** to conclude that there exists a sequence ${N_n}$ going to infinity with ${n}$, such that ${Z_{n,\leq N_n}}$ still converges in distribution to ${N(0,1)}$.

However, I don't see how the diagonalization argument works. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.